# using for loop to get random objects from one array and add them to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to get random objects from one array (inventory) a certain amount of times and push them into a new array (randomInventory). The code below does not work. Any help on what would work?

```
    var inventory = activity.options;
    var randomInventory = new Array();   
    var i;
    var item;
      for(i=0; i>10; i++){
        item = inventory[Math.floor(Math.random()*inventory.length)];
       randomInventory.push(item);
      } 
alert(randomInventory);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very close. You need to change `i>10` to `i<10`. Aside from that, it depends on what the remainder of your function looks like but it should be good to go. This below works:

```
const go = () => {
   var inventory = [1,2,3,4,5];
   var randomInventory = new Array()  
   for(var i=0; i<10; i++){ // change to i<10
     var item = inventory[Math.floor(Math.random()*inventory.length)];
       randomInventory.push(item);
    } 
  return randomInventory
}

console.log(go())
```

Comment: thanks! for some reason it didn't occur to me that I had the wrong symbol for the condition.Such a basic error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to shuffle, you can do this:

```js
var original = [{one: 1}, {two: 2}, {three: 2}];
var shuffled = randoSequence(original).map(i => i.value);

console.log(shuffled);
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

If you actually don't care about repetitions and want different lengths to be possible, you can do this:

```js
var original = [{one: 1}, {two: 2}, {three: 3}];
var randomized = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) randomized.push(rando(original).value);

console.log(randomized);
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

This code uses [randojs.com](https://randojs.com), so if you want to use it, just make sure this is in the head of your html document:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```